# Android TV Input HAL EPG support and timeshifting

Tags: android, android-tv, television, hal, epg

I am writing an Android TV Input HAL implementation and looking at the the tv input Hal interface I don't see an interface to be implemented that will provide support for EPG, channel names and timeshifting as the Android documentation says.

I am writing this tv input implementation for a custom tv hardware which has support for all these features but I can't seem to find the right interface in the Android TV Input hal to plug this into.

I only see 
getStreamConfigurations : which is a way get available streams but only there IDs and supported resolutions.

And 
openStream : which then opens one of the above streams for a particular surface and assigns to the surface as a sidebandStream

Can any body please help on this.

The hal is present at

hardware/interfaces/tv/input/1.0/ITvInput.hal with it's types.hal also

And a sample place holder module at

hardware/libhardware/modules/tv_input

Am I supposed to extend the HAL somehow?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @abielita it's not a coding problem , I'm in the design phase I want to first know which protocol do I need to comply while adding TIF support for custom hardware , I have not written any code I'm asking about the hidl interface as described in the Android documentation and the recommendations and protocols for TV support in the Android CDD.